# Class instance declaration syntax error in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to play with classes in python. I tried to run the following code.

```
class Abc:
    def a(self):
        print ("not to be seen")
    def b(self):
        print("inaccessible is")
        self.a

say = Abc()
say.b
```

I am expecting the output as

```
inaccessible is
not to be seen
```

Instead I get the following output:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

with say highlighted.

Please somebody point out what I am doing wrong.

Edit: I'm using IDLE GUI. Python 33 says the Python docs.

Comment: Please post the *full* exception message. Being able to read these is an important skill.

Comment: Please post the actual code (with indentation).

Comment: Apart from whatever results in the `SyntaxError` here, `self.a` is *not* actually calling anything, instead this syntax returns a function, that when called evaluates `Abc.a(self)`. You want both `self.b()` and `self.a()` in your code.

Comment: Which version of Python are you running?

Comment: If you don't post the full exeption message including the traceback, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: @larsmans

I'm using IDLE GUI and it highlights the first 'say' and says syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

Python likes to make syntax very clear - the `()`s after a function are not optional when calling a function without parameters like in some other languages.

You're not calling the functions just 'stating' them.

Try

```
class Abc:
    def a(self):
        print ("not to be seen")
    def b(self):
        print("inaccessible is")
        self.a()

say = Abc()
say.b()
```

[Here is the code working.](http://repl.it/JrD)

Syntactically, the code is valid.

Comment: "Python likes to make syntax very clear - the ()s after a function are not optional when calling a function without parameters like in some other languages.". It's semi correct, it wont call it but it won't produce a `SyntaxError` either

Comment: @limelights Right, but it wouldn't produce OP's expected result which is calling the function - just like in languages like JavaScript and C# and unlike other languages like CoffeeScript and Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it. You need to call the functions by adding `()`, like so:

```
class Abc:
    def a(self):
        print ("not to be seen")
    def b(self):
        print("inaccessible is")
        self.a()

say = Abc()
say.b()
```

Actually I'm puzzled why your code throws a syntax error. In Python, it is valid to state a function.

Comment: Still, tt says syntax error and the first say is highlighted. Isnt that how class objects are created? I'm using IDLE GUI.
Its Python version 3.3.0 and relese 3.3

Answer (score 0):

OK, I could reproduce your error by installing idle for Python 3.3.0. I'm sorry that we all suspected that you didn't include the whole error message because IDLE doesn't produce more than a red `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. There is nothing wrong with your code, nor your class definition.

I guess, you're just pasting the code as-is into your Python shell window. This way, things won't work because the indentation doesn't get produced correctly.
Try pasting the line `class Abc:` into your shell window and press `Enter`. You will see that IDLE automatically indents the next line with a tab. This is the correct indentation for the following line, so when you enter it, you need to paste `def a(self):` without any extra indentation! If you paste line by line and reduce the indentation by one where needed and terminate your class definition with an extra `Enter`, your code gets executed correctly.

However, you should better use the following method:

- Paste your file into an editor and save it as `whatever.py`
- In IDLE, choose `File -> Open` and open this file
- A new window opens with your source code inside.
- Now, press `F5` or say `Run -> Run Module`
- Your code will be executed and the result displayed in the Python Shell.

Or, even better, use Python directly in the shell by executing `python whatever.py` directly.